# Fit element width of current screensize in an universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to develop an app for Windows 10. But with the all new screensizing I can't seem to figure out how to get an element to fit to the current size of a device screen.

For example I want a TextBlock to fit the width of the window if you resize it. I've tried the ViewBox, VariableSIzedWrapGrid etc etc but nothing seems to fix my problem. Anyone knows?
[image]

**Update:** It's the searchbox I'm trying to fit to the size of the window below. The grid fills the whole window and so does the RelativePanel if I put a background color on it. But the SearchBox refuses to strech... I don't want the searchbox to to scale in size, just it's width to fit the window/device width.

```
        <!-- SEARCH GRID -->
    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="5" x:Name="GridSearchPackage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="0.85" Background="White">
        <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,0,0" >
            <Button x:Name="ButtonBackSearchGrid" Height="36" Width="36" FontSize="10" Margin="0,7,5,0"
                  Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"
                  Click="ButtonBackSearchGrid_Click"
                  AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                  AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
                <FontIcon x:Name="backButtonIcon" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="{StaticResource AppDarkBlueColor}" Glyph="&#xE72B;" />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPopupSearchTitle" RelativePanel.RightOf="ButtonBackSearchGrid" Foreground="{StaticResource AppDefaultBlueColor}" Text="Search XZY" FontSize="34"/>
            <SearchBox FontSize="20" RelativePanel.Below="TextBlockPopupSearchTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" PlaceholderText="search" Margin="0,10,0,0" QuerySubmitted="SearchBox_QuerySubmitted" QueryText="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What does your XAML look like? You should be using `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: Updated post with XAML

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are using `RelativePanel`, you might want to set `AlignLeftWithPanel` and `AlignRightWithPanel = true` to make the entire horizontal space available for the `TextBlock` (and similarly `AlignTopWithPanel`, `AlignBottomWithPanel=true` for vertical). Most `UIElements` have `HorizontalAlignment`/`VerticalAlignment = Stretch` as the default, but you might want to set that explicitly as well to ensure the actual visual of the `TextBlock` is stretched across the screen.

When the window is resized, the element will automatically resize using the above settings. You don't need to use a `ViewBox` here to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you! AlignRightWithPanel and AlignLeftWithPanel worked when setting it on the SearchBox

Answer (score 0):

To let a FrameworkElement stretch to fill its container set its [HorizontalAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) to Stretch. It's difficult to see this with the TextBlock though since it doesn't have a background and the text within the TextBlock doesn't stretch. You can add a HorizontalAlignment on a surrounding ViewBox if you want to stretch the Text.

```
<ViewBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform">
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet" />
</ViewBox>
```

The other thing to check is that the container your TextBlock is in fills the window. Most will by default if you don't override it.

Comment: Yes the ViewBox seems to strech it's width but it also scales it's height and font-size. I just want the textbox/searchbox width to extend the whole way of the window.

Comment: TextBox/SearchBox vs. TextBlock and RelativePanel both greatly change the scenario. See Harini's answer for the updated question.